# PDO - Execute query every minute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to run this query every minute that the user is on the page.

```
$unitquery = $db->query("SELECT LID, address1, address2, city, state, zip FROM tbl_Locations WHERE HID = '$homeID' GROUP BY LID");
$uq = $unitquery->FetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I do not want to refresh the page or anything like that, I just want to execute this query again and again and again every minute while the user is on the page. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes - just call the page via an AJAX call - every time you call the page it will execute - then just set an interval of 60 seconds on a loop around your call - there is loads of info on this already on SO

Comment: SQL injection. What is the purpose of that, your are not querying for the love of querying, aren't you?

Comment: @RC. no, it's just an example. the query i am actually doing is a lot more complicated. i just put something like this in here as an example. :)

Comment: This doesn't answer to my question is this something you use to update something displayed to your user, is this something only running in background, ...?

Comment: @RC. The query I will be using on my page is checking to see if a record has been updated within the last minute. The query in my question has nothing to do with why I am asking the question.

Comment: OK, let me try again, what should php do if the record has been updated? what should php do if the record has not been updated?

Comment: If the record has been updated, the user is redirected to a different page. If the record has not been updated, I have a loading bar that notifies the user that the website is checking their records for the update. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ok so ajax or websockets is the way as it's UI related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different approaches:

- 1st approach: Invoke the php script from the client-side using ajax (using setInverall on the client-side for example)
- 2nd approach: Keep an open connection between client and server and execute the code every minute (using sleep or whatever on the server-side)

Comment: 1st approach seems like a much better idea to me, no?

Comment: yes, usually the first approach is clearly the better one but in some situations (f.e. chat) the second approach sometimes works better (since you know much faster when a user leaves the page).